# render graphics after inputting information in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server

I am trying to generate some graphs after entering certain parameters, however, while some graphs are being entered they throw an error because the input has not yet been entered, so the idea occurred to me if the value was null, do not make the graph but annex code is not working:

```
shinyApp(ui =
           fluidPage(sidebarPanel(numericInput('x','x', value = NULL),
                                  numericInput('x2','x2', value = NULL),
                                  numericInput('x3','x3', value = NULL)), 
                     mainPanel(renderPlot('plot1'))),
         
         server = function(input, output, session){
           
         condition <- reactive(is.null(input$x) | is.null(input$x2) |is.null(input$x3))
         
         output$plot1 <- renderPlot(if(condition()){NULL}else{plot(1:10,1:10)})
         
         })
```

I would appreciate a way to do it, thanks.

Comment: Maybe use the [req function](https://rdrr.io/github/sheikhbarabas/shiny/man/req.html) for required parameters. your example doesn't seem to produce any errors so it's difficult to use for testing possible solutions. How exactly is the code "not working"?

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your `ui` code that prevents to display any plot at all, you should replace :

```
mainPanel(renderPlot('plot1'))
```

with :

```
mainPanel(plotOutput('plot1'))
```

As stated in @MrFlick comment, you can use `req()` for required inputs:

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot(
  {
    req(input$x, input$x2, input$x3)
    plot(1:10,1:10)
  })
```